# window.open title appended with web browser name

Tags: javascript, html

A window opened by `window.open` has title appended by web-browser name. For Chrome it has 'Google Chrome'. For IE, it has 'Internet Explorer".

Is there a way to make it not add the web-browser name?

Comment: No. [need characters]

Comment: In the example by W3Schools you just get the title tag as window name: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open. What do you do different?

Comment: @randy it's popup window, not a window opened in a tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browsers add their own name so malicious websites could not trick the user into thinking the windows it's open by another program.

So the answer is no.